# What is a stifle

Tags: meaning

I've read in a dictionary that a stifle is the joint next above the hock in the hind leg of a quadruped (such as a horse or dog) corresponding to the human knee. Also to stifle means to prevent something from happening and to feel unable to breathe.
There is a sentence where I can't get the meaning of this word:

> > Company after company dashed into the blazing "fireproof" building, urged by the hoarse profanity of the chief. Twenty or thirty men must
> >     have disappeared into the **stifle** from which the police retreated.
> >     There was no haste, no hesitation. Everything moved as smoothly as if
> >     by clockwork.

The speaker's discribing the action of a fire. How it happened. Maybe those men died from the lack of air?

Comment: Please give an attributed link. It looks non-standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth i added some context. Thanks for your straightaway answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extract appears to be taken from an article or story titled "The Firebug" in "The Cosmopolitan", Volume 52, at p572 (Schlicht & Field, 1912) Google Books has a "snippet view".

From the definition below, I assume that "stifle" here is an extended meaning of

> OED
>   3. (n.) 1886   J. Barrowman Glossary of Scottish Mining Terms 64   *Stifle, noxious gas resulting from an underground fire.*

i.e. the noxious atmosphere (smoke and fumes) inside the burning building.

Comment: Thank you for help! I should have guessed that but i didn't